# restframework show objects in html but not id

Tags: django

Rest-framework support post data in the web.

But about ForeignKey,it shows just the same "Objects" without feature to make sure which is what I want.

[image]

this is my code:

server models:

```
node = models.ForeignKey(
    Node,
    related_name='server',
    null=True,
)
```

serializers:

```
class ServerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = ( 'node')
```

How can I get the server objects' feature instead of "Server Object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a [`__unicode__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__unicode__#object.__unicode__) method for your model to have more readable representation. Assuming your model has a field `name` which contains the name of the object, do something like:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In Case you are using [Django with Python3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) you should use instead the `str()`:

```py
    class Server(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```